# How do i use swift mailer library to send email message in symfony2.7?

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer

**what i have done so far?**

I have a webController class This class i created pingserviceAction 
i want to send email to all the urls  i.e primary_url in my case
how could i achieve this Thanks in advance

Source Code of controller is given below

```
 <?php
  namespace MWANMOBILE\Bundle\BIBundle\Controller\Admin;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;

  use MWANMOBILE\Bundle\BIBundle\Entity\Web;
  use MWANMOBILE\Bundle\BIBundle\Form\Type\ServiceType;
  use MWANMOBILE\Bundle\BIBundle\Form\Type\UserType;

  class WebController extends Controller
   {
      public function pingserviceAction(Request $request)
        {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $web_list = $em->getRepository('MWANMOBILEBIBundle:Web')->allWeb();

    //  $web_url = $em->getRepository('MWANMOBILEBIBundle:Web')->allWebUrls();
    // var_dump($web_list); 
    //  exit();

        $site_status = '';

        foreach ($web_list as $single_web_list)
        {

        $url= $single_web_list['primary_url'];
        $st_email = $single_web_list['status_email'];
        $st_message = $single_web_list['status_message'];


        $ch = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        if (!200==$retcode) {

            echo("comon"); 
            $subject= "sorry server is down due to maintenance work ";

            $site_status.='site_down ';

            $to = array('zarghamirtza@gmail.com');
            $this->getMailer()->composeAndSend('blueeyed_riu@yahoo.com', $to, $subject , $st_message);

        } else
         {
            $site_status.='site_active ';
         }

        }

        exit();
 }
```

}

Attempted to call an undefined method named "getMailer" of class "MWANMOBILE\Bundle\BIBundle\Controller\Admin\WebController".

Comment: replace ``$this->getMailer()`` with ``$this->get('mailer')``

Comment: and read this cookbook entry http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

Comment: Thanks for helping when i use  $this->get('mailer')  it gives me error like this Attempted to call an undefined method named "composeAndSend" of class "Swift_Mailer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using method which does not exists: `getMailer` (there was such method in `Symfony 1.x`)

To get mailer you need to get mailer service by calling `$this->get('mailer')` and use `send` method which takes `Swift_Message` instance as an argument. So all you need to do is replace:

```
$this->getMailer()->composeAndSend('blueeyed_riu@yahoo.com', $to, $subject , $st_message);
```

with:

```
 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setFrom('blueeyed_riu@yahoo.com')
    ->setTo($to)
    ->setBody($st_message);

 $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Check [official howto](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html) for more info

Comment: thanks for guiding me , i have one more question how do i test either email is sent or not from local host ? how can i use smtp of gmail ?

Comment: you really need to check documentation, it's all there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete working method that you can copy paste:

```
/**
 * @param $to
 * @param $from
 * @param $subject
 * @param $body
*/
protected function sendEmail($to, $from, $subject, $body)
{
    $email = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setContentType("text/html")
        ->setBody($body,'text/html');

        $this->container->get('mailer')->send($email);
}
```

Its also stated over here: https://reformatcode.com

Comment: I am using the same in Symfony 2.8 but get Error :-   Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class

Comment: If your using it in a controller try instead of:

$this->container->get('mailer')->send($email);

this:

$this->get('mailer')->send($email);

Comment: Yes i am using $this->get('mailer')->send($email); and getting Error messege   "Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class"

Answer (score 0):

In Command (checked in Symfony 3.1) you have to use getContainer():

$this->getContainer()->get('mailer')->send($message);